# count and tag element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, count, attributes

This is a sample of a very long poem. More than 3.000 verses:

```
<lg n="1" subtype="count">
   <l>Danske Christne! hvor I findes,</l>
   <l>Flokkes ved vor Biskops Liig!</l>
   <l>Lad os her det Svundne mindes!</l>
   <l>Mindes Gud og Himmerig!</l>
   <l>Gud og Himlen, som med Taarer</l>
   <l>Vi maa sige, svandt fra Jord,</l>
   <l>Svandt for Tant af usle Daarer,</l>
   <l>Som omtaaged Sandheds Ord;</l>
   <l>Svandt, thi Gud er fra os svundet,</l>      
   <l>Naar i <hi rend="spaced">Hjertet</hi> ei Han boer,</l>
</lg>
```

I want to put a `n`-attribute on every fifth `<l>`-element in order to make it possible to refer to a specific verse in an easy way. With these two templates I end with a `n`-attribute on every `<l>`-element:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
          <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="TEI:lg[@subtype='count']/TEI:l">
          <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:attribute name="n">
                    <xsl:number/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

How do I get this result?

```
<lg n="1" subtype="count">
   **<l n="1">**Danske Christne! hvor I findes,</l>
   <l>Flokkes ved vor Biskops Liig!</l>
   <l>Lad os her det Svundne mindes!</l>
   <l>Mindes Gud og Himmerig!</l>
   **<l n="5">**Gud og Himlen, som med Taarer</l>
   <l>Vi maa sige, svandt fra Jord,</l>
   <l>Svandt for Tant af usle Daarer,</l>
   <l>Som omtaaged Sandheds Ord;</l>
   <l>Svandt, thi Gud er fra os svundet,</l>      
   **<l n="10">**Naar i <hi rend="spaced">Hjertet</hi> ei Han boer,</l>
</lg>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: *" to make it possible to refer to a specific verse in an easy way"* - would XPath such as `/lg/l[42]` not already be an easy way to refer to any `<l>` in your document? What improvement would these additional attributes bring?

Comment: Your output has the attribute on the 1st,  5th and 10th `l`. That is not "on every fifth `<l>`-element".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="l">
    <xsl:variable name="num"><xsl:number level="single"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$num = 1 or matches($num, '(0|5)$')">
            <xsl:attribute name="n" select="$num"></xsl:attribute>    
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcwV

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: One more question. How do I modife your templates if for instance two or more <lg>-elements are wraped in say a <div>-element: <div><lg><l></l> ... </lg> <lg><l></l>...</lg> ...</div>? I stil want to count <l>-elemnets from start to end? Does this makes sense?

Comment: I change value in level to any!